# alsa - managing non-blocking stream

Tags: usb, centos, alsa

Working with a usb audio device (its a HID with multiple channels) that constantly outputs data.

What I'm hoping to achieve is to ignore the audio until a signal comes in from the device. At that point I would start monitoring the feed. A second signal from the device would indicate that I can go back to ignoring the data. I have opened said device in non-blocking mode so it won't interfere with other USB signals coming in.

This is working fine except that when I start reading the data (via `snd_pcm_readi`) I get an EPIPE error indicating a buffer overrun. This can be fixed by calling `snd_pcm_prepare` every time but I'm hoping there is a way to let the buffer empty while Im ignoring it.

I've looked at `snd_pcm_drain` and `snd_pcm_drop` but these stop the PCM and I'd rather keep it open.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the PCM device running? Have you measured a latency for `snd_pcm_start` that is too high?

Comment: Well - that's a great question. Maybe I can ignore it by simply.. well.. ignoring it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore buffer overruns, change the PCM device's software parameters: set the stop threshold to the same value as the boundary.
With that configuration, overruns will not cause the device to stop, but will let it continue to fill the buffer.
(Other errors will still stop the device; it would be hard to continue when a USB device is unplugged ...)

When an overrun has happened, the buffer will contain more data than actually can fit into it, i.e., `snd_pcm_avail` will report more available frames than the buffer size.

When you want to *actually* start recording, you should call [`snd_pcm_forward`](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gad0774fa8991248c6f1c264aaeb0b4207) to throw away all those invalid frames.